# Filter dataset based on regexp for end of strings

Tags: sql, r, regex

I am working with REGEXP to filter a dataset with 10 lines looking like:

```
ID     Product
1      "VENLAFAXINE HCL CAP ER 24HR 37.5 MG (BASE EQUIVALENT)"
2      "MINOXIDIL POWDER"
3      "MENTHOL LOZENGE 10 MG"
4      "ZINC CHLORIDE GRANULES"
5      "CLOPIDOGREL BISULFATE TAB 75 MG (BASE EQUIV)"
6      "METHYLPREDNISOLONE TAB THERAPY PACK 4 MG (21)"
7      "DEXAMETHASONE TAB THERAPY PACK 1.5 MG (7)"
8      "METHYLPREDNISOLONE DOSE P (16)"
9      "MILLIPRED DP (13)"
10     "ZONACORT 7 DAY"
```

And would get it to look like

```
ID     Product
6      "METHYLPREDNISOLONE TAB THERAPY PACK 4 MG (21)"
7      "DEXAMETHASONE TAB THERAPY PACK 1.5 MG (7)"
8      "METHYLPREDNISOLONE DOSE P (16)"
9      "MILLIPRED DP (13)"
```

In effect, I want to filter the dataset based on if the last characters are numbers within parentheses. I have tried using to no avail:

```sql
SELECT ID, Product
FROM DAT
WHERE product like '%[(][0-9][)]';
```

Comment: `Like` does not use a regex.

Comment: Question is about use of `regexp` and that tag has been added by OP.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `r` by the way?

Comment: @mck my fault! i'm used to asking questions in `r` but this is a general question

Comment: I have removed the `r` tag to avoid confusion. As this is on databricks, are you using Spark SQL?

Comment: @mck Yes I am using Spark SQL via Databricks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `RLIKE` to match a regex pattern:

```
SELECT ID, Product
FROM DAT
WHERE product RLIKE '\\([0-9]+\\)$';
```

Answer (score 6):

In `base R`, we can use `grepl` to match the opening parentheses (`\\(`) followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`), then the closing parentheses (`\\)`) at the end (`$`) of the string

```
subset(df1, grepl("\\(\\d+\\)$", Product))
#    ID                                       Product
#6  6 METHYLPREDNISOLONE TAB THERAPY PACK 4 MG (21)
#7  7     DEXAMETHASONE TAB THERAPY PACK 1.5 MG (7)
#8  8                METHYLPREDNISOLONE DOSE P (16)
#9  9                             MILLIPRED DP (13)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, Product = c("VENLAFAXINE HCL CAP ER 24HR 37.5 MG (BASE EQUIVALENT)", 
"MINOXIDIL POWDER", "MENTHOL LOZENGE 10 MG", "ZINC CHLORIDE GRANULES", 
"CLOPIDOGREL BISULFATE TAB 75 MG (BASE EQUIV)", "METHYLPREDNISOLONE TAB THERAPY PACK 4 MG (21)", 
"DEXAMETHASONE TAB THERAPY PACK 1.5 MG (7)", "METHYLPREDNISOLONE DOSE P (16)", 
"MILLIPRED DP (13)", "ZONACORT 7 DAY")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support regular expressions.  But you could do:

```
WHERE product like '%([0-9]%)' AND
      product NOT LIKE '%(%[^0-9]%)'
```

The first condition checks that there are parentheses with a digit in the middle at the end of the string.

The second validates that all the characters between the parentheses are numbers.

That said, this is not perfect but it will work if there are no other parentheses in `product`.